# Can you predict the polynomial degree of the numerator and denominator of a rational functions inverse?

Tags: functions

I have graphed out certain rational functions linear/linear, quadratic/quadratic, and linear/quadratic and quadratic/linear. I am wondering provided that I know the polynomial degree of the numerator and denominator of the rational functions can I predict the degree for the rational functions' inverse?

Comment: Not always they have inverse

Comment: If you mean "inverse" in the sense of function composition (as opposed to multiplicative inverse) then the typical rational function doesn't _have_ an inverse, and if it does have an inverse the inverse is typically not another rational function.